# Calling Curl from python throwing illegal char in URL

Tags: python, curl

```
os.system("curl \"http://localhost:8181/api?apikey=0918e28bf971b021f9d7533ffdf6ad02&cmd=findArtist&name=%s&limit=1\" -o tmpartist.txt" %artist)
```

I get this error `curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL` the artist this is tested with is `Taylor%20Swift`

The api I'm using is headphones https://github.com/rembo10/headphones/blob/master/API.md

Comment: As a side note, there's no need to use curl this way in python. We have such a wonderful [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) lib.

Comment: Thanks! How can I parse the requests object to grab just the id: when the api returns `[{"url": "http://musicbrainz.org/artist/20244d07-534f-4eff-b4d4-930878889970", "score": 100, "name": "Swift, Taylor", "uniquename": "Swift, Taylor", "id": "20244d07-534f-4eff-b4d4-930878889970"}]` I looked at python's string methods but none of them looked like they would work for grabbing just the info in the last set of ""

Comment: This is called "json" - look it up.